# intersection point between circle and line

Tags: analytic-geometry

The line  $-bx + ay + 2b = 0$  intersects circle on points A and B.  Circle equation is $$(x-1)^2 + \big(y-\frac{a^2 + b^2 - a}{b}\big)^2 = \frac{(a^2 + b^2 - a)^2 + b^2}{b}$$ 
or after algebraic-transformations: $$bx^2 + by^2 - 2bx - 2(a^2 + b^2 - a)y =0 $$
Find the intersection points. One of them is $(2, 0)$. Thanks for any help for this hard task.

Trying mathematica :

$$x_1\to \frac{-2 b+\frac{2 a^2 b}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{a^3 b}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{a b^3}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{a \sqrt{32 b^2 \left(-a^2-b^2\right)+\left(4 a b+2 a^2 b+2 b^3\right)^2}}{2 \left(a^2+b^2\right)}}{b}$$

$$y_1\to \frac{4 a b+2 a^2 b+2 b^3-\sqrt{32 b^2 \left(-a^2-b^2\right)+\left(4 a b+2 a^2 b+2 b^3\right)^2}}{2 \left(a^2+b^2\right)}$$

$$x_2\to \frac{-2 b+\frac{2 a^2 b}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{a^3 b}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{a b^3}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{a \sqrt{32 b^2 \left(-a^2-b^2\right)+\left(4 a b+2 a^2 b+2 b^3\right)^2}}{2 \left(a^2+b^2\right)}}{b}$$

$$y_2\to \frac{4 a b+2 a^2 b+2 b^3+\sqrt{32 b^2 \left(-a^2-b^2\right)+\left(4 a b+2 a^2 b+2 b^3\right)^2}}{2 \left(a^2+b^2\right)}$$

But something is wrong because one solution must be (2,0).

EDIT:

This problem can be discribed by picture. In picture $O(1, \frac{a^2 + b^2 - a}{b})$, $A(2,0)$, $D(2a+2,2b)$ and $C(?,?)$. Equation of line and circle is in first line of my post.

[image: image1]

Comment: What's stopping you from using any of the techniques you've learned for solving a system of two equations in two variables?

Comment: I have just edited my question. There's my answer :)

Comment: The equation for your circle is wrong then: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282-1%29%5E2+%2B+%280-%28a%5E2%2Bb%5E2-a%29%2Fb%29%5E2

Comment: Incidentally, once you have the equations right, there's a cute trick: once you eliminate $y$ and get a quadratic equation in $x$, you can divide out by $x-2$ because you know that's a solution already! (This would be more obvious if you eliminated $x$ first, I suppose)

Comment: Thanks. It's preety obvious but i forgot about it :) Thanks a lot. Second point is x = 2(a^3 - a^2 + ab^2 + b^2)/(a^2+b^2) && y = b(2 - (4a)/(a^2 + b^2) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, an easier method just dawned on me.

- Construct the line L through O perpendicular to DA.
- Find the point E where L intersects DA
- The vector AC is twice the vector AE.